# Handling empty rows/cells in JSON - Power BI Querying

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Searched everywhere but couldn't find something similar to this.

I got a table as below (a glimpse of it):
`customDimensions` is the column that pulls the data in JSON format. However, there are some empty cells (as seen below) in the column.

[image]

I tried to Parse the whole column into JSON but it is returning me errors in the blank columns as below:

[image]

Therefore I tried an alternative way of first replacing those blank cells in the `customDimensions` to a generic JSON format input as `{"Type":"Unhandled"}` and then Parsed the column into JSON. This successfully got rid of the errors, but it is returning error while refreshing the data!

So, How do I handle this in a different way? I want to replace those blank cells as either "null" or any keyword, as long as I do not miss the count of those blank cells.

**EDIT**

Re: `This successfully got rid of the errors, but it is returning error while refreshing the data!` The error is as follows:

[image: Error while refreshing the data]

[image]

[image]

And that specific error is as above

**EDIT 2:**[image]

Comment: `This successfully got rid of the errors, but it is returning error while refreshing the data!` Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Please look at the EDIT section. I have added 3 screenshots. 
1) is the error while refreshing
2) is the error returning in all the cells of those expanded JSON (Type.1 is the generically added JSON format)
3) is the specific error when clicked on the error

Comment: Did you actually use `{"Type.1":"Unhandled"}` to replace the blank values or something else? Can you provide a single record and also the M query because I can't reproduce the error with the given information.

Comment: No I have used `{"Type":"Unhandled"}` but when I tried to expand the JSON by not checking "Use original column name as prefix", it is returning me with the column name as `Type.1`

Comment: I have added another screenshot of it, please check @FoxanNg

Comment: It's quite hard to debug without a record in this case.. Can you provide an anonymized one? Is it because you've already had another column named `Type` in the table?

Comment: Yes I have provided another name as `{"Exception_type":"Unhandled"}` but still the same error is coming up without `.1` this time. Is this error something to do with the refresh because in reality, the created column `"Exception_type"` didn't exist at all or what?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the field name. Can't really proceed without sample data. If you create a separate .pbix with the details you've given above you'll realize it's working fine.

Comment: Oh is it?! Or probably is there an alternative way to handle this issue? I don't want to lose those empty cells.

Comment: you were right! It is not something to do with the field name or refresh. The error was due to the fact that this column has got couple of "null" values apart from the empty cells. I have been only replacing the empty cells with `{"Exception_type":Unhandled"}` and not the null values. This time I've replaced the null values too and it worked! Thanks for your comments, it made me think

Comment: OK cool. I've also just come up with a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got trapped in the XY Problem but actually you can just replace the error after parsing the JSON instead:

[image: error]

[image: replace error]

[image: replace error with blank]

Repeat with all columns and it'll be fine.

[image: results]